# Strange issue with replit's express option (24/7 coverage without premium payments)

Tags: discord.js

I've been recently using replit to host my discord.js bot, but after dealing with many errors, I can't stop my bot, I mean, I can, but it doesn't log off of discord and express is still loaded up, should I just wait or, is it something else? Any form of help will be appreciated. Btw, it isn't giving me any errors, so it might be a problem with express (which is basically Flask but for JavaScript). And yes, I paused UptimeRobot, if it won't work, I will just load up a backup

Answer (score 0):

I won't recommend hosting bots using this method. You can get yourself a cheap vps or maybe AWS Free tier or GCP Free tier and host there!